# How to make UIAlertView don't dismiss depending on the buttonIndex

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

Hi :D I'm making an app where I have an UIAlertView which I don't want to dismiss when `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated`'s buttonIndex is 1, but if it's not 1 it should dismiss. How can I achieve it? Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can implement its delegate:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

and in its body you can check if buttonIndex is one or not and act accordingly